# Wordpress Shortcodes not working in php format

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am using a plugin called wp-like-lock. It has a integrated shortcode `[wp-like-lock]` .It works fine in post if i use like this below :

```
[wp-like-lock]content[/wp-like-lock]
```

But i want to integrate in template.And using like this :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[wp-like-lock]"); ?>
    content
<?php echo do_shortcode("[/wp-like-lock]"); ?>
```

But now it not working.It comes exactly like this on page : `content[/wp-like-lock]`

Is anything wrong i am doing? I have also tried with single-quotation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo do_shortcode( '[wp-like-lock]' . $content . '[/wp-like-lock]' )
```

[Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)